# What are the problems of using of array in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, search

I have the following Java class:

```
public class A
{
   public Integer mat [] [];
   public A(int length)
    {
       mat = new Integer[length][length];
     }
   public boolean Check(Integer key)
   {
     for(int i = 0;i<mat.length;i++)
        {
           for(int j =0;j<mat.length;j++)
              {
                if(mat[i][j] == key)
                {
                    return true;
                 }
               }
          }
       return false;
 }
}
}
```

}

and use class `A` in this code:

```
public class Main Activity
{
  ...
   List<Integer> lt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   lt.add(2);
   lt.add(3);
   lt.add(4);
   lt.add(5);
  A objA = new A(Math.sqrt(lt.size()));
  lt.toArray(objA.mat);
  boolean b = objA.Check(1);
   ...
}
```

When the application is run, this error shows up:

> Unfortunately,Main has been Stopped

What is the problem here?

Comment: What does LogCat say?

Comment: Shouldn't your code in `MainActivity` be in any method or any `block` ??

Comment: What do you think this does: `lt.toArray(objA.mat);` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: Thanks,,,but there aren't.how i do?

Comment: I edited the question. I know it is hard to overcome the language barrier. But you expect people to put effort into answering your question. Be so kind to put at least the same effort into your question. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor of Class A takes integer argument.

Sqrt returns double value.

> public static double sqrt(double a)
>   Returns the correctly rounded positive square root of a double value.

How did you run the app with this compile time error?

Comment: Maybe you have another constructor that you didn't share. Anyways, please share the logcat.

Comment: ##### ERROR : timer_thread: tick delayed > 5 slots (-54881391,-50000000) -- cpu overload ? #####

Comment: how i do?this is the log ca